# How to solve $5x+9y=n$?

Tags: induction

Show that $n_0 = 32$ is the smallest value of $n$ for which the equation $5x+9y=n$ has a solution in $(\mathbb N \cup \{0\})^2$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Wouldn't $(x,y)=(1,1)$ be a valid solution for $n=14$?

The example that appears before this question consider $(x,y)=(1,1)$ as a solution for $3x+5y=n$ in $(\mathbb N \cup \{0\})^2$ for $n \geq 8$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. cf. [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you asked for the smallest value of $n_\color{red}0$?

Comment: Because there is no solution to $5x+9y = 16 \geq 14$, so 14 isn't the smallest number that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the lowest value, I didn't realize that for 15, 16, ... there was no solution.

Comment: There is a solution for $15$ -- $(x,y)=(3,0)$ -- but not for $16$

Comment: Yeah, true, just wanted to say that for n greater than 14 there are values with no solution.

Comment: That's more complicated than this question in my book, but thanks, I'll try to understand what is said there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x,y)=(1,1)$ is a valid solution for $n=14$, but I think the question asks for the smallest $n_0$ such that $5x+9y=n$ has a soution for all $n\ge n_0$, and there's no solution for $5x+9y=16>14$ in non-negative integers.

**Addendum to answer OP's additional question:**

$31$ cannot be expressed as $5x+9y$ with non-negative integers $x,y$, but

$32=5(1)+9(3)$,
$33=5(3)+9(2)$,
$34=5(5)+9(1)$,
$35=5(7)+9(0)$,

and
$36=5(0)+9(4)$,

and  if $n-5$ can be expressed as $5x+9y$ with non-negative integers then $n$ is $5(x+1)+9y$.

Comment: Ahh, I see. But how do I show that? I don't understand the example.

Comment: Are you asking how you show that $5x+9y=16$ has no solutions in non-negative integers?

Comment: No, how do I show that 32 is the smallest value that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Can you show there's not a solution for $31$?

Comment: That tells you the smallest value is at least $32$, and my addendum shows it's not more than $32$

Comment: Thank you so much! 